# Does the Psycopg2 "copy_from" Function (or the PostgreSQL COPY command) Support Sequence "nextval()" Function Values

Tags: python, postgresql, relational-database

I have a database that I am inserting large amounts of rows at a time (~100,000).  From the PostgreSQL documentation, it seems like the use case for the "COPY" command are mostly for moving databases, backing up databases to a CSV, etc.  My use case doesn't seem to be under the same realm as the use cases listed previously, but I believe it would improve the insert performance.

Right now, I am trying to test the Psycopg2 Python library's function "copy_from" command with a small CSV file.  The primary key is a sequence integer that I have previously been using the nextval('seq_key') function to find the value for.  Now that I have switched to the "copy_from" command, I have created a CSV file that holds the values:

```
nextval('seq_key'),4,1573946481,'Test1', now(),now()
nextval('seq_key'),4,1573946481,'Test2', now(),now()
nextval('seq_key'),4,1573946481,'Test3', now(),now()
```

I am calling the "copy_from" command with the following code:

```
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.copy_from(test_file, "test_master", sep=",", null="NULL")
    conn.commit()
```

I am getting the error:

`"invalid input syntax for integer: "nextval('seq_key')"`

When I remove the `nextval('seq_key')`, the program ends up working and inserts the rows into the table.  I was wondering if there was something special I would have to do in order to get the "nextval()" function working.  Also if someone could explain why the "nextval()" function doesn't work, but the "now()" function does that would be great too.  I could also fetch the current sequence value and insert and increment the value into the CSV and then update the sequence with the "setval()" function, but I figured I would try to learn more about the Psycopg2 library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question....

It seems that both PostgreSQL's COPY command and Psycopg2's "copy_from" function do not support `nextval('seq_key')`, but they do support `now()` and other functions that do not need to make continuous reads from the database.  It is also important to note that if `now()` is used, all the entries will have the same value for that column even if it takes multiple seconds to copy all the rows into the database (which makes sense since you are trying to insert them all at the same time).

I was able to get around this problem by not specifying a value for the sequence number and allowing it to use the default value of `nextval('seq_key')`.  I am fairly new to PostgreSQL, so there may be useful database functions that would also not be allowed when using the COPY command.  For `nextval('seq_key')`, this isn't a big deal since you would usually want to use this anyway, but there may be more PostgreSQL functions that don't work with COPY that might not be as straight forward as `nextval('seq_key')`.

Anyway, hope this helps someone out there!  Kind of an obvious question/solution, but if anyone has any questions, just let me know!

Comment: I have a insert in one table in batches. Each batch has its own connection and transaction, but runs in the same program.
Subsequent connection executions are giving me errors because the first one works(think 50000 records), but the second one tries to insert in the 50000 id (which is occupied already). 
However if I open a psql session, the sequence only adds one per batch, so after 9 batches, I get a 9 value on the sequence. 
So, copy_from internally works with it well, but checking from outside this value does not correlate - but still changes. Any idea?